# Style Qt radio buttons to look similar to UISegmentedControl?

Tags: qt, radio-button, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I style Qt radio buttons to look like IOS's UISegmentedControl?  Here's an example of that control:

[image]

A similar example from the web, that also demonstrates the desired behaviour of the buttons, is shown under the heading "Horizontal radio button sets" here:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html

I'm expecting to use QRadioButtons in a QButtonGroup, but if some other widget and/or container makes it easier to achieve this effect, that's probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the desired behaviour by subclassing a QRadioButton and reimplementing paintEvent.  paintEvent can use Qt's built-in rendering for QPushButton, combined with use of Qt stylesheets to achieve the desired look (pushing the buttons together and rounding the buttons on the end).

Here is some example code [from the PySide documentation](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QStyleOption.html) that is almost exactly what is needed (and is also very similar/identical to the corresponding PyQt code):

```
def paintEvent(self, qpaintevent):
    option = QStyleOptionButton()
    option.initFrom(self)
    if isDown():
        option.state = QStyle.State_Sunken
    else:
        option.state = QStyle.State_Raised

    if self.isDefault():
        option.features = option.features or QStyleOptionButton.DefaultButton
    option.text = self.text()
    option.icon = self.icon()

    painter = QPainter(self)
    self.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, option, painter, self)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this using QML it would be pretty easy. Here's a quick demo of something I made in about one minute. You'd then need to connect it appropriately to what every you're using it for. If you want to make it more fancy then this, I would suggest using image files instead of rectangles.

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "grey"

    Item{
        id: root
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle{
            id: button
            radius: 5
            color: "transparent"
            width: 100
            height: 50
            smooth: true

            Rectangle{
                id: leftButton
                height: parent.height
                width: 45
                color: "black"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: parent.radius
                smooth: true
            }
            Rectangle{
                id:leftButtonEdge
                height: parent.height
                width: 10
                radius: 5
                anchors.right: leftButton.left
                anchors.rightMargin:-width / 2
                color: "black"
                smooth: true
            }

            Rectangle{
                id: rightButton
                height: parent.height
                width: 45
                color: "white"
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.rightMargin: parent.radius
                smooth: true
            }
            Rectangle{
                id:rightButtonEdge
                height: parent.height
                width: 10
                radius: 5
                anchors.left: rightButton.right
                anchors.leftMargin:-width / 2
                color: "white"
                smooth: true
            }

            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("Clicked")
                    if(rightButton.color == "#000000"){
                        rightButton.color = "white"
                        rightButtonEdge.color = "white"
                        leftButton.color = "black"
                        leftButtonEdge.color = "black"
                    }else{
                        rightButton.color = "black"
                        rightButtonEdge.color = "black"
                        leftButton.color = "white"
                        leftButtonEdge.color = "white"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting.  I ended up not going this route because it would mean re-implementing the built-in rendering of QPushButton, which is already style-able to be exactly what I need.

Comment: @Croad Not sure why you would need to re-implement the rendering of QPushButton if you are working with QML?

Comment: stackunderflow: because I want it to look like a QPushButton.

Comment: @CroadLangshan Hmm couldn't you just implement your own custom QML element derived from the QPushButton, something like what is shown [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Creating_a_custom_QML_element_with_Qt). It wouldn't be as simple, but this would give you the same styling as the QPushButton.